# What is the difference between Spark Structured Streaming and DStreams?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have been trying to find materials online - both are micro-batch based - so what's the difference ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until Spark 2.2, the `DStream[T]` was the abstract data type for streaming data which can be viewed as `RDD[RDD[T]]`.From  Spark 2.2 onwards, the `DataSet` is a abstraction on `DataFrame` that embodies both the batch (cold) as well as streaming data.

From the docs

> Discretized Streams (DStreams) Discretized Stream or DStream is the
>   basic abstraction provided by Spark Streaming. It represents a
>   continuous stream of data, either the input data stream received from
>   source, or the processed data stream generated by transforming the
>   input stream. Internally, a DStream is represented by a continuous
>   series of RDDs, which is Spark’s abstraction of an immutable,
>   distributed dataset (see Spark Programming Guide for more details).
>   Each RDD in a DStream contains data from a certain interval, as shown
>   in the following figure.
>
> API using Datasets and DataFrames Since Spark 2.0, DataFrames and
>   Datasets can represent static, bounded data, as well as streaming,
>   unbounded data. Similar to static Datasets/DataFrames, you can use the
>   common entry point SparkSession (Scala/Java/Python/R docs) to create
>   streaming DataFrames/Datasets from streaming sources, and apply the
>   same operations on them as static DataFrames/Datasets. If you are not
>   familiar with Datasets/DataFrames, you are strongly advised to
>   familiarize yourself with them using the DataFrame/Dataset Programming
>   Guide.

Answer (score 7):

Brief description about Spark Streaming(RDD/DStream) and Spark Structured Streaming(Dataset/DataFrame)

**Spark Streaming** is based on **DStream**. A DStream is represented by a continuous series of RDDs, which is Spark’s abstraction of an immutable, distributed dataset. Spark Streaming has the following problems.

Difficult - it was not simple to built streaming pipelines supporting delivery policies: exactly once guarantee, handling data arrival in late or fault tolerance. Sure, all of them were implementable but they needed some extra work from the part of programmers.

Incosistent - API used to generate batch processing (RDD, Dataset) was different that the API of streaming processing (DStream). Sure, nothing blocker to code but it's always simpler (maintenance cost especially) to deal with at least abstractions as possible.

see the [example](https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/introduction-to-spark-streaming/)

Spark Streaming flow diagram :-
[image: Spark Streaming flow diagram]

**Spark Structured Streaming** be understood as an unbounded table, growing with new incoming data, i.e. can be thought as stream processing built on Spark SQL.

More concretely, structured streaming brought some new concepts to Spark.

exactly-once guarantee  - structured streaming focuses on that concept. It means that data is processed only once and output doesn't contain duplicates.

event time - one of observed problems with DStream streaming was processing order, i.e the case when data generated earlier was processed after later generated data. Structured streaming handles this problem with a concept called event time that, under some conditions, allows to correctly aggregate late data in processing pipelines.

sink,Result Table,output mode and watermark are other features of spark structured streaming.

see the [example](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/01/19/real-time-streaming-etl-structured-streaming-apache-spark-2-1.html)

Spark Structured Streaming flow diagram :-

[image]